# Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 13.0.1

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sdk, version

> cordova build android --release
> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME= (DEPRECATED)
> Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 13.0.1
> Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.
    
    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Everything is in the error message. Have you tried to change the `JAVA_HOME` or `PATH` env. variable to set a Java 8 JDK instead of JDK 13 ?

Comment: apart of setting properly variables you should
1. close and open terminal to reflect changes
2. delete windows cache as this can ben sometimes cached and brings headache when trying to solve this issue